# Mouse Click on XNA

Tags: c#, xna, mouse

I am trying to update my player by mouse click. I have tried different actions on player to update such as free drag. They work. But mouse click does not work. Can anybody help me?

For more detail, my player class holds animation texture and its position. I am trying to change another texture to current one.

It works. I mean: when I drag the player its animation changes. It means my class functionality has no problem. But when I try the same thing with mouse click, it does not work.

```
//initialize method 
player.Initialize(player1, player1.Position);

//update method
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

    UpdatePlayer(gameTime);
    _bgLayer1.Update(gameTime);
    _bgLayer2.Update(gameTime);

    base.Update(gameTime);
}

//update player method
void UpdatePlayer(GameTime gameTime)
{
   player.Update(gameTime);

   // Touch inputs
   while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
   {
       GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

       if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.FreeDrag)
           player.Position += gesture.Delta;
           player.PlayerAnimation = player2;   
   }

   // Get Mouse State
   if (previousMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
   {
       player.PlayerAnimation = player2; 
   }
   previousMouseState = currentMouseState;
}
```

Comment: `does not work` is not enough information. Please be more specific and detailed.

Comment: You should debug your code with a breakpoint to see if the program enters that *if*. But if you are sure that it works, remember that it lasts only one update cycle, maybe it's too fast to see.

Comment: Your code for update via mouse is correct. That, indeed, should set the PlayerAnimation to player2 when the left button is clicked. Make sure you don't change PlayerAnimation back to something else elsewhere (such as in the Draw() method or in the player.Update() method). Also, you have a bug in your code. The line "player.PlayerAnimation = player2" will be executed on all gestures, not only on free drag. (This is why you should always put braces after an if condition, in my opinion.)

Comment: I don't understand where you have `if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.FreeDrag)`, the code that you have below it is indented as it was in your *if*, but only the first row will be a consequence of it. Are you missing any brackets?

Comment: ı missed the brackets. But it still works. ı dont know how.